# vpasolve (Matlab) cannot find root of equation when piecewise is used (root clearly exists)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the root of this equation, which is only function of H:

```
syms H
eq = piecewise(H < 0.624, - 98.3*H^6 - 0.961*H^3 + 6.94*H^2 + 2.41e-8, H < 1.56, 6.94*H^2 - 5377.0*(0.641*H - 0.4)^3 - 5077.0*(0.641*H - 0.4)^2 - 0.961*H^3 - 98.3*H^6 + 2.41e-8, 1.56 <= H, - 98.3*H^6 - 0.961*H^3 + 6.94*H^2 - 2988.0);
H = vpasolve(eq==0,H);
```

However vpasolve returns empty 0x1 sym.
If I plot with:

```
fplot(eq2), xlim([0.5 0.51]), ylim([-0.1 +0.1])
```

You clearly see that it crosses the y=0 axis around 0.506. [image]
In fact:

```
double(subs(eq,0.5062))
```

Gives   -8.2450e-05.

the culprit seems to be the piecewise function. Clearly the first condition is satisfied by H and the solution is the solution of - 98.3*H^6 - 0.961*H^3 + 6.94*H^2 + 2.41e-8. If  remove piecewise the solver works:

```
syms H
eq - 98.3*H^6 - 0.961*H^3 + 6.94*H^2 + 2.41e-8;
H = vpasolve(eq==0,H);
```

which gives

```
H =

                                                 -0.52458969841163012770887662427408
                                                  0.50619380851052153463867425194323
- 0.00000000024038304755545478229904837943596 + 0.000058924789608363053116092886242865i
- 0.00000000024038304755545478229904837943596 - 0.000058924789608363053116092886242865i
          0.0091979451909373440905559684644729 - 0.51555587519744206224638650619188i
          0.0091979451909373440905559684644729 + 0.51555587519744206224638650619188i
```

An the positive real solution is the sought one. But in general, I need the piecewise, why is not the solver working? Workarounds?

Edit:

Some of you are suggesting to use "solve" that actually works. I actually tried solve before posting but I ruled it out cause it is 5 times slower than vpasolve (tested on only first equation so with no piecewise). I need to solve this thousands of times for different parameters. it would be great if this bug with vpasolve could be solved, nowhere it states that vpasolve does not accept piecewise functions

Comment: When you write `fplot(eq2)`, is `eq2 == eq` in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `vpasolve` is compatible with piecewise function, but I'm sure that `solve` is, so you can use:

```
res = vpa(solve(eq==0,H))
```

And we obtain two roots:

```
res =  0.5026 
      -0.5245
```

Also are you sure to have set the right condition ?

```
H < 0.624 -> eq1
H < 1.56  -> eq2
H >= 1.56 -> eq3
```

eq1 and eq2 are overlapping, I would use `0.624 <= H < 1.56 -> eq2` in order to get things clear. And if you only want positive and real solution you should also add this condition directly in your equation:

```
0     <= H < 0.624  -> eq1
0.624 <= H < 1.560  -> eq2
H     >=     1.560  -> eq3
```

And use `assume`:

```
assume(H,'real')
```

So now the things are perfectly clear.

Comment: I actually "tried" solve before posting but I ruled it out cause it is 5 times slower than vpasolve (tested on only first equation so with no piecewise)....it would be great if this bug with vpasolve could be solved, nowhere it states that it should not accept piecewise functions

Comment: I need to solve this thousands of times for different parameters. That is the problem, so it would be nice to have the 5-fold speed improvement.